# Cannot send email from Liferay Web Forms

Tags: tomcat, smtp, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I am using Liferay Web Forms for email sending purposes.

Done so far:

- Setup the form title and description.
- Altered the input field names.
- Ticked the "Send Email" functionality, set up mail title and address.
- Changed portal settings so that virtual host name, email server name and sender email address from my own domain

I can get this to work on my local development machine if I add the smtp configurations on `portal-ext.properties` and `conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`

My problem is on putting this to another server machine, with a different tomcat server installed and no previous `conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` folder existing. I took a bundle from internet and don't know how the folder is set up to my dev machine i.e. I don't know how this should be configured on a machine which does not previously have that file.

Do I have to make some changes before the tomcat finds the added ROOT.xml? I already restarted server with no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Web Form portlet will use mail configurations set by a preference in Control Panel.

Goto Control Panel > Server Administration > Mail to configure the Mail settings.

Answer (score 2):

RP is correct with regards to configuration location in his answer. You can also have it in portal-ext.properties, as long as the file has a dash and not an underscore in the name (this is either a typo in your question here or in your setup - in the later case it'd be the reason for the settings not being picked up)

Comment: Does this mean that setting the preferences through the Control Panel alone is enough and there is no need to do any mail server settings in the ROOT.xml? I am asking because in the development environment, I have done the mail settings only through the control panel and I can send the form data to my email, but with the same settings on a production server I can't get the form data to my email. Are there any more settings I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can send the mail by following the link below using spring mvc and liferay    
http://javaeasyforu.blogspot.in/2013/11/sending-mail-in-liferay.html
```